# error en PHPExcel

Tags: php, html, web, phpexcel

Estimados tengo el siguiente problema al tratar de generar la lectura de un archivo de excel el código no tenia presentaba problemas la semana pasada y no tenido cambios, adjunto imagen del error [image: error que presenta la pagina]

Esto empezó a ocurrir desde el cambio de año, he revisado en el servidor por si tenia fallas o si la fecha presentaba algún error pero todo estaba ok

adjunto el codigo de la que tiene la pagina, de todas formas en varias tengo el mismo problema el codigo es similar y el error siempre empieza en el FOPEN()

```
<?php
    require_once('./includes/config.php');
    require_once('./includes/metas.php');
    include("ini.php");
    $fecha_ingreso =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //conexiones, conexiones everywhere
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    //Aquí es donde seleccionamos nuestro csv
        $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
        echo 'Cargando nombre del archivo: '.$fname.' <br>';
        $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);
        if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
        {
        //si es correcto, entonces damos permisos de lectura para subir
            $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
            $indx = 0;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
            {
                if ($indx > 0 and $data[0]<>''){

                    $newDate=$data[0];           
                    $fecha_primera_llamada = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($newDate));
                    $hora_primera_llamada=$data[1];
                    $numero_telefono=$data[2];
                    $id_agente=$data[3];    
                    $sql2= "SELECT * from base_registros_epa where fecha_primera_llamada ='$fecha_primera_llamada' and hora_primera_llamada='$hora_primera_llamada' and numero_telefono='$numero_telefono' and id_agente='$id_agente';";
                    $stmt=$db->query($sql2);  
                    $existe=0;
                    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                        $existe++;
                    }

                    if ($existe==0) {
                        //Insertamos los datos con los valores...
                        $sql="INSERT INTO base_registros_epa (fecha_primera_llamada,hora_primera_llamada,numero_telefono,id_agente,fecha_carga_base)
                        values('$fecha_primera_llamada','$hora_primera_llamada','$numero_telefono','$id_agente','$fecha_ingreso')";
                        $stmt=$db->query($sql);
                    }
                    
                }
                $indx++;
            }
            //cerramos la lectura del archivo "abrir archivo" con un "cerrar archivo"
            fclose($handle);
            ?>
                <script languaje="javascript">
                    alert("Importacion Existosa!!!");
                    location.href = "buscador_registro_epa.php";
                </script>
            <?php
        }else{
        //si aparece esto es posible que el archivo no tenga el formato adecuado, inclusive cuando es cvs, revisarlo para             
        //ver si esta separado por " , "
            ?>
                <script languaje="javascript">
                    alert("Registros NO Importados!!!");
                    location.href = "buscador_registro_epa.php";
                </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

agradecería de su ayuda la verdad que he buscado durante todo el día la solución pero no he conseguido dar con ella, por favor maestros algún consejo con para solucionar este problema

Comment: Buenas primero que nada, tu imagen es muy pequeña, y en realidad no se aceptan imagenes en esos casos. SI es un error, por favor copia y pega todo lo importante del error.

Comment: Ahora, el error menciona que `filename` está vacío, lo que me lleva a entender que no has controlado el caso de error en el que el `filename` nunca se cargue, y por ende, llegue vacío a esa instancia.

Comment: Cruzando archivo bajo el nombre de : busqueda_parque.csv
nombre : busqueda_parque.csv<br/>    

Warning: fopen(busqueda_parque.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ccwom/public_html/descarga_parke.php on line 20
arcihvo :<br/>  

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ccwom/public_html/descarga_parke.php on line 25<br/>

Comment: `No such file or directory` no existe dicho archivo acá...

Comment: es que eso es lo raro, yo estoy seleccionando el archivo desde otra pagina, de hecho me sale el nombre del archivo, pero en estas lineas   $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");   pierdo la referencia, el problema es que en todas las paginas se encontraba de igual forma y no presentaba problemas hasta la semana pasada, gracias por tu ayuda Excorpion

Comment: No es buena idea manipular un archivo desde la carpeta **temporal**, mejor muévelo a otra ubicación, haz lo que debas hacer y, si ya no lo necesitas, lo borras.